# Why is this text disappearing but not the shape?

Tags: javascript, canvas

How do I make the shape disappear like the text does? I've gone through the code and they're practically identical except that one is created when the user spins the mouse wheel and the other is created when the user clicks on the screen, but the text disappears after time and the triangle does not. I feel like there's something small I must be missing. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var canvas;
var context;
var triangles = [];
var texts = [];
var timer;
var textSayings = ['Cool!', 'Nice!', 'Awesome!', 'Wow!', 'Whoa!', 'Super!', 'Woohoo!', 'Yay!', 'Yeah!', ':)', ':D'];

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //resize canvas to fit the window
    resizeCanvas();
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeCanvas, false);

    canvas.onwheel = function(event) {
        handleWheel(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    };

    canvas.onclick = function(event) {
        handleClick(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    }

    var timer = setInterval(resizeCanvas, 30);
}

function Triangle(x,y,triangleColor) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.triangleColor = triangleColor;

    this.vx = Math.random() * 80 - 40;
    this.vy = Math.random() * 80 - 40;
    this.time = 250;
}

function Text(x,y,textColor,word) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.word = word;
    this.textColor = textColor;

    this.vx = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
    this.vy = Math.random() * 20 - 10;
    this.time = 300;
}

function handleWheel(x,y) {
    var colors = [[255,0,0],[255,255,255],[0,0,255]];
    var triangleColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    triangles.push(new Triangle(x,y,triangleColor));
    for (var i=0; i<triangles.length; i++) {
        drawTriangle(triangles[i]);
    }
}

function handleClick(x,y) {
    var colors = [[255,0,0],[255,255,0],[0,0,255]];
    var textColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    texts.push(new Text(x,y,textColor,pickWord()));
    for (var i=0; i<texts.length; i++) {
        drawText(texts[i]);
    }
}

function timeToFade(time) {
    if(time > 100) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return time / 100;
    }
}

function pickWord() {
    return textSayings[Math.floor(Math.random() * textSayings.length)];
}

function drawText(text) {
    context.font = "bold 80px Verdana";
    var gradient=context.createLinearGradient(0,0,canvas.width,0);
    gradient.addColorStop("0","magenta");
    gradient.addColorStop("0.25","yellow");
    gradient.addColorStop("0.5","lime");
    gradient.addColorStop("0.75","aqua");
    gradient.addColorStop("1.0","magenta");
    context.fillStyle = gradient;
    context.fillText(text.word,text.x,text.y);  
}

function drawTriangle(triangle) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(triangle.x,triangle.y); 
    context.lineTo(triangle.x+25,triangle.y+25);
    context.lineTo(triangle.x+25,triangle.y-25);
    var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0,0,canvas.width,0);
    gradient.addColorStop("0","red");
    gradient.addColorStop("0.25","salmon");
    gradient.addColorStop("0.5","aqua");
    gradient.addColorStop("0.75","lime");
    gradient.addColorStop("1.0","orange");
    context.fillStyle = gradient;
    context.fill();
}

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth-20;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight-20;
    fillBackgroundColor();
    for (var i=0; i<triangles.length; i++) {
        var t = triangles[i];
        drawTriangle(t);

        if (t.x + t.vx > canvas.width || t.x + t.vx < 0)
            t.vx = -t.vx
        if (t.y + t.vy > canvas.height || t.y + t.vy < 0)
            t.vy = -t.vy
        if (t.time === 0) {
            triangles.splice(i,1);
        }

        t.time -= 3;
        t.x += t.vx;
        t.y += t.vy;
    }
    for (var i=0; i<texts.length; i++) {
        var te = texts[i];
        drawText(te);

        if (te.x + te.vx > canvas.width || te.x + te.vx < 0)
            te.vx = -te.vx
        if (te.y + te.vy > canvas.height || te.y + te.vy < 0)
            te.vy = -te.vy
        if (te.time === 0) {
            texts.splice(i,1);
        }

        te.time -= 3;
        te.x += te.vx;
        te.y += te.vy;
    }
}

function fillBackgroundColor() {
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
    context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
}

window.onload = init;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the triangle time isn't a multiple of 3, while the text time is so when you check this if statement:

```
if (t.time === 0) {
    triangles.splice(i,1);
}
```

It's never true.

You can fix this by changing the if statement to:

```
if (t.time <= 0) {
    triangles.splice(i,1);
}
```

This is actually my fault since it's a bug that was in my previous answer. Sorry about that.

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0rst8def/

Comment: Ah, thank you I knew it was something small like that. Nothing to apologize for, I really appreciate your help!